# Keras Model with Maxpooling1D and channel_first

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

I have a problem with my current attempt to build a sequential model for time series classification in Keras. I want to work with `channels_first` data, because it is more convenient from a perprocessing perspective (I only work with one channel, though). This works fine for the `Convolution1D` layers I'm using, as I can specify `data_sample='channels_first'`, but somehow this won't work for `Maxpooling1D`, which doesn't have this option as it seems.

The model I want to build is structured as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=35, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, window_length), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5)
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', data_format='channels_first'))
[...] #several other layers here
```

With `window_length = 5000` I get the following summary after all three layers are added:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 32, 4966)          1152     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 4, 4966)           0        
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)           (None, 16, 4957)          656      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,808
Trainable params: 1,808
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Now, I wonder if this is correct, as I would expect the third dimension (i.e. the number of neurons in a feature map) and not the second (i.e. the number of filters) to be reduced by the pooling layer? As I see it, `MaxPooling1D` does not recognize the `channels_first` ordering and while the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) says there exists a keyword `data_format` for `MaxPooling2D`, there's no such keyword for `MaxPooling1D`.

I tested the whole setup with a `channels_last` data format, and it worked as I expected. But since the conversion from `channels_first` to `channels_last` takes quite some time for me, I'd really rather have this work with `channels_first`. And I have the feeling that I'm simply missing something.

If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: Reading the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/pooling.py#L57), it looks like you can just pass `data_format='channels_first'`.

Comment: @HSK When i try to do so (`model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=8, data_format='channels_first')`) i get an error `TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'dataformat')`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code; reading up to where `class Layer` is actually defined, it does not accept `data_format` as one of the keyword arguments. I thought it accepts `data_format` as it calls `K.pool2d(inputs, pool_size, strides, padding, data_format, pool_mode='max')`, but the rest of the source code assumes everything is in `channels_last`. Unfortunately, it looks like you would have to implement this yourself if you want to use `channels_first` if I didn't miss something.

Comment: No harm done. I tried it out before, because it was the natural thing to try first. But it's good to know, that I'm not the only one confused by this.

Comment: I made a PR regarding this and is now merged. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/10966

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: [as mentioned by @HSK in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962106/keras-model-with-maxpooling1d-and-channel-first/51963170#comment90905682_51962106), the `data_format` argument is now supported in `MaxPooling` layers as a result of [this PR](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/10966).

---

Well, one alternative is to use the [`Permute`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#permute) layer (and remove the `channels_first` for the second conv layer):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=35, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 100), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Permute((2, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5))
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=16, kernel_size=10, activation='relu'))

model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_7 (Conv1D)            (None, 16, 66)            576       
_________________________________________________________________
permute_1 (Permute)          (None, 66, 16)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 13, 16)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_8 (Conv1D)            (None, 4, 16)              2096      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,672
Trainable params: 2,672
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```